# How does this code function?

Tags: c++, string

This is a piece of exercise code.

```
int main()
{
    string s1 = "A string example";
    string s2 = "A different string";

    if (s1 < s2) {
        cout << "true";
    } else {
        cout << "false";
    }
}
```

what confuses me is that the code insists that s2 is less than s1. Am I missing something, I'm assuming it calculates this by the amount of characters in the string so what have I missed since s1 clearly has less characters?

Comment: It uses [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: No, that's not how strings are compared. [Google for it](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=c%2B%2B+string+comparison&safe=active), don't just assume.

Comment: *I'm assuming it calculates this by the amount of characters in the string so what have I missed since s1 clearly has less characters?* Think about what would happen if string equality was the number of characters in a string... `"a" == "b"` would be true...

Comment: If you want to compare based on number of characters do: `s1.length() < s2.length()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It calculates it using the ASCII values of the characters in the string. In this case, the first differing characters are `'s'` in `s1` and `'d'` in `s2`. Since `'d' < 's'`, the comparison evaluates to `false`.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense. Thanks for the help, I was expecting the answer to be mind boggling. So simply, because d is the 4th letter in the alphabet and s is the 19th. S is a higher value and it applies this in the code?

Comment: More specifically, `'d'` is represented by the number 100 and `'s'` by the number 115 in US-ASCII. Here's a complete chart: http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html

Comment: AFAIK, an implementation is free to produce the opposite result. ASCII itself is getting rarer and rarer (if there are characters past 127, it's not strict ASCII), and not every character set is ASCII-compliant.

Comment: that's brilliant. That was really confusing me. honestly a lot of this confuses me since i'm an absolute beginner, i'd seen this site a few times and tried it out and the replies are so fast, unlike any other site. Hopefully I'll be able to understand more of this now. Thanks again for the help though.

Comment: @chris `std::string` uses `char_traits<char>::compare` which will always use the less than operator.

Comment: @AndrewDunn, And what the less than operator returns depends on the character set in use. For example, EBCDIC is a valid and used character set, although even it has `'d' < 's'`. I know for a fact that the alphabet doesn't have to be contiguous, but I haven't heard for or against it being in order.

Comment: @chris There's so much code out there now that relies on `'a'` through `'z'` being consecutive and positive that it seems unlikely anyone will ever make changes to the values `0` through `127` !

Comment: @MattMcNabb, EBCDIC is one thing still in use today, and it doesn't satisfy that. Important to note if one needs to write a library that can be used on such a system.

Comment: @chris I mean that no new systems designed to replace current ASCII systems will use non-ASCII for that range. We aren't going to see EBCDIC cell phones

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I sure hope you're right about that :) Any new system would be mad not to keep compatibility with ASCII, and I'm just waiting for someone to come along and disprove that.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above by another answer, the numerical ASCII values of each character in each string is evaluated to determine if `string` **s1** < `string` **s2**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    string s1 = "A string example";
    string s2 = "A different string";
    if (s1 < s2) {
        cout << "true";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "false";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Application Output

```
false
```

Further to your question, to determine character `length` in the comparison, the following code would accomplish this as the `length` method of each `string` is being used for the comparison:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    string s1 = "A string example";
    string s2 = "A different string";
    if (s1.length() < s2.length()) {
        cout << "true";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "false";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Application Output

```
true
```

Comment: This helps to, thanks. It's good to see another perspective of the code that matches how I thought it would function.

Answer (score 0):

You've stumbled upon the fact that whether something is *"less than"* or *"greater than"* has a number of possible interpretations.  It so happens that the class known as `std::string` uses lexicographical order by default.  And that leads to what you might think are counterintuitive results, like "2" being bigger than "10".

This is a fundamental issue...because being able to sort things in a known order matters a lot in C++.  In fact, with many collections you can pass in a comparison function that is different from the default you'd get if you just used the `<` operator.  See [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), and how to override that in collections like 'map'.

In some sense, there is no right and wrong, but then there must be a *consistent* ordering.  You *could* create your own string class with your own rules where longer strings are greater... but as has been pointed out to you, that would carry implications for equality as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming it calculates this by the amount of characters in the string

Your assumption is incorrect.

`s1 < s2` invokes the [following function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) from the standard library:

```
template< class CharT, class traits, class Alloc >
bool operator<( const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& lhs, 
                const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& rhs );
```

The comparison is done [*lexicographically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) and is performed by a function equivalent to [`std::lexicographical_compare()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare).

Lexicographical comparison is a operation with the following properties:

- Two ranges are compared element by element.
- The first mismatching
  element defines which range is lexicographically less or greater than
  the other.
- If one range is a prefix of another, the shorter range is
  lexicographically less than the other.
- If two ranges have equivalent
  elements and are of the same length, then the ranges are
  lexicographically equal.
- An empty range is lexicographically less
  than any non-empty range.
- Two empty ranges are lexicographically
  equal.